# Удаленный доступ к серверу?

Tags: сервер

Ситуация в следующем, я нахожусь в разъездах и порой мне требуется удаленная работа с моим сервером, кто ни будь вкурсе, из хостеров кто может предоставить подобное при размещении своей машинки ?

Answer (score 1):

Солокэйшн? Linux или венда? В случае с линуксом - запускай VNC или SSH, а с вендой - по протоколу RDP. Если своя машинка то в чем проблема-то? Почти все хостеры предоставляют доступ по SSH к серверу. Например majordomo.ru, у меня там не свой сервер, а просто VDS, но доступ по SSH вплоть до root-пользователя есть.

Answer (score 0):

В предыдущем посте вам ответили почти всё. Могу поделиться только своим опытом до кучи. Мне хватает колокейшн, размещаю пару своих серверов в московском дата-центре, а компания называется PlanetaHost.ru
У них есть возможность удаленного доступа к серверу, именно так и работаю.
Про VPS\VDS тут по опыту могу сказать, что хороший хостинг лучше чем средний по качеству VPS. Но каждому своё.. мне VPS мало

Comment: Если вы размещаете свои сервера в датацентре то ведь вы по умолчанию их подключаете к 100/1000 мегабитке с доступом в интернет и получаете на них выделенный IP адрес, соответственно установив любую из современных серверных ОС вы получите к ней удалённый доступ, просто его настроив, причем тут хостер?

Comment: при том, что когда дата-центр рядом, даже тот же сервер свой туда пердать намного проще не говоря уж про другие плюсы

Comment: попиарить решил человек хостера.
А по факту любой нормальный провайдер предоставляет услугу статического внешнего айпи (обычно это стоит не более 1-2 долларов в месяц). Главное, что бы комп был включен.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну не всегда это удобно, 1-2 доллара за выделенный IP + плата за электричество + расходы на ИБП + расширение исходящего канала + если отключится интернет ваш интернет-провайдер не попросит у вас даже прощения за предоставленные неудобства.

@Nikcooz, а причем тут близко или далеко датацентр? Разговор про удалённый доступ, пусть хоть в Германии дата-центр. Наличие удалённого доступа зависит только от администратора сервера и наличия подключения к сети Интернет.

Comment: мой провайдер (не буду указывать имя, не для рекламы) выдает статический айпи. привязываем к любому DynDNS и радуемся жизни. А комп могут и домашние включить.

Comment: Если статический IP то не нужно привязываться к DynDNS нужно просто настроить NS записи у регистратора твоего домена, а DNS можно заюзать на своём серваке, например подробно рассказывается про один популярный демон DNS тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/137587/

Comment: @cyberdream, согласен. Я просто не до конца понял вопрос видимо.